# Is it ok to reference a JPA entity that has been deleted?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I have a JPA entity that links to others -- something like this:

```
@Entity
class LinkRec implements Serializable {
    ...
   @OneToOne
   private OtherEntity otherTable;
     ...
}
```

So my logic eventually can delete this entity (calling the `EntityManger.remove` method), then I want to write to a log file what was done, including reference members of the **otherTable** object.   Is this a permitted operation in JPA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a permitted operation in JPA?

Yes.

What JPA (underlying JPA provider) does when you invoke `remove` is just "mark" that the instance is expected to be deleted/removed. But even if the transaction is committed (and the instance deleted from the database) or not, the instance object remains the same. Any changes on its attributes depend on what you do.

Due to you mark the entity as *removed* you won't can refresh the instance's state from the database (call `EntityManager.refersh` method). You will get an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Be aware that, in other cases, you could screw up if you `refresh` the entity before loggin what you want.

I quote a text from the JPA specification (see [Synchronization to the Database](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) section) that could help you to understand the "JPA" behaivor

> Synchronization to the database does not involve a refresh of any managed entities unless the refresh operation is explicitly invoked on those entities or cascaded to them as a result of the specification of the cascade=REFRESH or cascade=ALL annotation element value

Comment: One followup:  If the member object is lazily loaded (and not loaded yet) would that be a problem?   That isn't going to be my case but I am curious about how JPA works.

Comment: Do you mean after `remove` invoked on `LinkRec`? In your case, you will can fetch it through the `otherTable` association before transaction is commited, and after transaction commit depends if the underliyng persistence context wasn't destroy/dispose it

Answer (score 1):

The relevant line in the spec is:

> After an entity has been removed, its state (except for generated state) will be that of the entity at the point at which the remove operation was called.

Since this is all I can find on the subject in the spec, I would say that it could vary from implementation to implementation. In my opinion, this makes what you are tying to do dangerous. It may work in one JPA implementation and not another, or work in one version and not in an upgrade.

If I had to guess on implementations, I would say that @OneToOne objects will probably work okay. Where I would worry is with things like @OneToMany. In the case of Hibernate for example: this collection may be hydrated and in memory, but it may also point to a proxy. If it is a proxy and you call the getter it will check with the database for the collection and fail to load it because the object is gone.

Comment: @Terrance I had similar thoughts but I would like to keep working on this.  My easiest workaround is just do the log entry before the operation which risks entering a bad log entry if the remove operation fails.  The next workaround is to compose the log entry before the operation and not send it to the log file until after the remove succeeds, but that is clumsy to code which I was trying to avoid.